# Regex MySQL, Find string with at least 2 letters and 2 numbers

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm using this regular expression `REGEXP '^([a-z]){2,}([0-9]){2,}$'`
to find strings with more than 2 letters and more than 2 numbers in combination with this `REGEXP '^([0-9]){2,}([a-z]){2,}$'`.
This covers only strings starting with numbers or ending with numbers.

I need one regex to find numbers in between letters also.

`MySQL version 5.1.73`

Comment: I think we should avoid usage of `?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to test column `val` then try the following:

```
...
WHERE (val REGEXP '^[0-9a-z]*$')
     +(val REGEXP '[a-z].*[a-z]')
     +(val REGEXP '[0-9].*[0-9]')=3
```

This combination will test `val` to be made up of *only numbers and characters* (first regexp), contain *at least two letters'* (second regexp) and *at least two numbers* (third regexp).

Comment: I get no results cars10 :/

Comment: I overlooked that the `REGEXP` returns 0 or 1, so it is easier to just add up all three results numerically. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you cars10! Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the longest:

```
^[[:alpha:]]{2,}[[:digit:]]{2,}$|^[[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{1,}$|^[[:digit:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}$|^[[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{2,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}$|^[[:digit:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{2,}[[:digit:]]{1,}$|^[[:digit:]]{2,}[[:alpha:]]{2,}$

mysql> select * from testtable;
+-------------+
| testcol     |
+-------------+
| 11aaa       |
| dd12        |
| s1s2        |
| 32423sdfsfd |
| sdfs12313   |
| saf234sfs   |
| asdf3sdf    |
+-------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from testtable where testcol regexp '^[[:alpha:]]{2,}[[:digit:]]{2,}$|^[[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{1,}$|^[[:digit:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}$|^[[:alpha:]]{1,}[[:digit:]]{2,}[[:alpha:]]{1,}$|^[[:digit:]]{1,}[[:alpha:]]{2,}[[:digit:]]{1,}$|^[[:digit:]]{2,}[[:alpha:]]{2,}$';
+-------------+
| testcol     |
+-------------+
| 11aaa       |
| dd12        |
| s1s2        |
| 32423sdfsfd |
| sdfs12313   |
| saf234sfs   |
+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for checking it out @PanosK.!

Answer (score 1):

Easy, but long. Use this:

```
(\d.*\p{L}+.*|\p{L}.*\d+.*)(?1)+|\d{2,}\p{L}{2,}|\p{L}{2,}\d{2,}
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/xT5rS6/6

### Explanation:

1. `\d{2,}\p{L}{2,}|\p{L}{2,}\d{2,}`: Handle the sure answer first. If it has 2 or more digits followed by two or more alphabet, or 2 alphabets then two digits.
2. `(\d.*\p{L}+.*|\p{L}.*\d+.*)(?1)+`: It can be just one digit/alphabet then followed by the other, then followed by one digit/alphabet again. Then I add `.*` to ignore other characters. `(?1)+` is **recursive regex** repeating the group one pattern. It needs to be repeated at least once if it only has 1 digit and one alphabet.

Comment: Thanks Aminah but I get `#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp`. I know this works in PHP but in MySQL it doesnt :/

Comment: Also, this will not test `'1aaa1' ` or `'a111a'` as positive.

Comment: @cars10, I already update the answer to match `1aaa1` or `a111a`

Comment: Yes,that did it! It works! But "easy" is something else in my mind, my head is smoking already ;-)

Comment: This fails with the string 'tes1t ma2tch'. I've added some unit tests to your regex101: https://regex101.com/r/xT5rS6/4

Comment: I've improved the regex. Still didn't test it in MySQL though, hehe. I hope it's helpful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zero width positive lookahead for one and normal pattern match for other:

```
^(?=.*[0-9]{2}).*[a-z]{2}
```

Comment: I get `#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp`